# How to delete Cube partition in SSIS

Tags: ssis, cube

How can I delete a cube partition in SSIS ? I
I have seen [this](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2008/09/15/ssis-create-analysis-services-partitions-from-a-ssis-package.aspx) example which shows how to create cube partition in SSIS but I am not able find tutorial for deletion of a cube partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using AMO, a Partition object has a Drop method.

```
myPartition = myMeasureGroup.Partitions.FindByName("Partition_Name");
if ( myPartition != null)
     myPartition.Drop();
```

Comment: Oh ! Let me try that and come back again. Thanks